# Aspx Page Level windows authentication?

Tags: asp.net

I have a document approval workflow application. The workflow sends emails to appropriate users with links for Accept/Reject the document.

When the user clicks on Accept or reject link, an aspx page is shown, where he can type a comment and submit.

Now the question is I want Windows Authentication on this aspx page. If the user is authenticated I want its Userid to be checked against database if his role/profile has priveledge to view the page.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: Can you have windows authentication on the entire site/application, or does it have to be just that page?

Comment: I use webservice as host to my workflow application. And there are few pages when user clicks on the Accept/Reject links. I cant have windows aunthentication on entire application. I just want user to be authenticated when he clicks on links in his email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the whole thing is internal (within your organization) then simply use Windows Authentication on the website. Other wise you have to mix Forms and Windows Authentication on the site. Here is an [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx) article about this.

Once authentication is wired up you can access the user's identity using static

```
System.Security.Principal.IIdentity user = Page.User.Identity;
```

property. It contains **IsAuthenticated** and **AuthenticationType** properties which you can put to use.